# ImageView with label that has a dynamic position for different sized images

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, autolayout, aspect-ratio

I am trying to create a simple gallery image detail view in my iOS 9 Swift app.

I want the image at the top and the label underneath (for an image caption). However, all the images are different shapes and sizes.

I am using Aspect Fit for the image view which creates a problem for landscape images.

The image view does not resize to adjust the image so you end up with blank space above and below it, which creates a big gap between my image and caption.

In the examples below the yellow is the image view, the blue is the image itself with aspect fit resizing and the pink is the caption label.

[Example Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwEdq.jpg)

Any solutions for getting the imageview to aspect fit the image, but clip the image view accordingly to remove unused space? I tried ticking "Clip Subviews" in the storyboard to no avail.

[Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxQYZ.png)

Comment: so - to stay in your example - you want to remove the unused yellow space, right?

Comment: Exactly - doesn't matter in the left hand example of course, but it affects the label position in the right hand example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the key is setting an aspect ratio constraint on the imageview.

```
class GalleryViewController: UIViewController {

  var image: UIImage!

  @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var captionLabel: UILabel!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let aspectRatio = image.size.width / image.size.height
    imageView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: imageView, attribute: .Height, multiplier: aspectRatio, constant: 0.0))

    imageView.image = image
    captionLabel.text = (aspectRatio < 1.0) ? "Portrait" : "Landscape"
  }

  @IBAction func viewWasTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  }

}
```

take a look at my sample project:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/oa8g96sknqqq97p/AADvEFpK2L9FbT-gBt5W49pQa?dl=0

Comment: Worked perfectly once I adjusted my constraints as per your example in the storyboard. Than you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your constraint configuration? I think if you let the height free it will fit to the image you put on it.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YxQYZ.png

I think this could well be the problem. I am having real problems getting the imageview to size itself appropriately and have the caption label below.

Comment: Your constraints are making the imageView height dependant on the view's height. You have attached the label to the view's bottom and the imageView to the label(and to view's top), so the imageView can't adjust the height automatically to its content. try removing the label-bottom view constraint, the imageView should fit the inner image and the label adjusts to the imageView.